# running multiple plot functions

Tags: r, plot

I am running the following plot commands and get the errors as shown below. I have read about how the evaluation frame treats default and specified values and was not clear on a solution. Any assistance appreciated.
Regards
SF.

> plot(c(9.6, 9.6), c(13.2, 14.8), xlim=xlim,ylim=ylim, col="gray", type='l',axes=F, xlab="", ylab="")

Error in plot.default(c(9.6, 9.6), c(13.2, 14.8), xlim = xlim, ylim = ylim,  : 
  object 'xlim' not found

> par(new=T)

Warning message:
In par(new = T) : calling par(new=TRUE) with no plot

> plot(c(9.6, 13.2), c(14.8, 14.8), xlim=xlim,ylim=ylim, col="gray", type='l',axes=F, xlab="", ylab="")

Error in plot.default(c(9.6, 13.2), c(14.8, 14.8), xlim = xlim, ylim = ylim,  : 
  object 'xlim' not found

> par(new=T
>   Warning message:
>   In par(new = T) : calling par(new=TRUE) with no plot
>
> plot(c(13.2, 13.2), c(14.8, 13.2), xlim=xlim,ylim=ylim, col="gray", type='l',axes=F, xlab="", ylab="")

Error in plot.default(c(13.2, 13.2), c(14.8, 13.2), xlim = xlim, ylim = ylim,  : 
  object 'xlim' not found

> par(new=T)

Warning message:
In par(new = T) : calling par(new=TRUE) with no plot

> plot(c(13.2, 9.6), c(13.2, 13.2), xlim=xlim,ylim=ylim, col="gray", type='l',axes=F, xlab="", ylab="")

Error in plot.default(c(13.2, 9.6), c(13.2, 13.2), xlim = xlim, ylim = ylim,  : 
  object 'xlim' not found

> par(new=T)
>   Warning message:

In par(new = T) : calling par(new=TRUE) with no plot

> text(11.4,14, "24", col="black")

Error in text.default(11.4, 14, "24", col = "black") : 
  plot.new has not been called yet

> par(new=T)

Comment: Hi Kristang, I want the plots to work - but as you can see currently I am getting the errors mentioned (object 'xlim' not found) - so the question was really to establish a solution or workaround to make it work. Thanks S

Comment: Well, we have no idea if you actually have xlim defined in your workspace.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you haven't yet defined `xlim` in your workspace.  If you want the x-axis to run from, say, 0 to 100, then in the workspace do

```
xlim <- c(0,100)
```

If you haven't already done the same for `ylim` be sure to do that as well. Then your code should work.

Comment: Thanks to Ben F and Kristang - Somebody elses C code had generated the script to run in R and indeed Xlim/ylim were not defined - I defined these and all working well now. Thanks again. Much appreciated.

Comment: Mark this as the answer so others can find it as well :)